# Crosscap function in $\mathbb{R}^4$ - and how to show it is proper?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis, differential-topology

I found the [Cross-cap](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-Cap.html) function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as follows:
$$f(x,y,z)=(yz,2xy,x^2-y^2),$$

**My questions are (I couldn't show any progress for Q1,2.I have thought hard but had no clue):**

---

Q1: Is there a form for crosscap in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

---

Q2: Is there a way to show this is proper (the preimage of a compact space is compact)?

---

Q3: Is there a way to show this is injective?

All my attempts are for linear functions, so none of them work.

I tried to show $f(x,y,z) = 0 \Rightarrow x = y = z = 0$. But I get $x=y=0$, with no constraint on $z$.

I tried to show $f(x_1,y_1,z_1) = f(x_2,y_2,z_2) \Rightarrow (x_1,y_1,z_1) = (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ but made no progress.

I tried to solve $f(x,y,z) = (a,b,c,d)$ for $x,y,z$ on [mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7Bx%20y,%20y%20z,%20x%20z,%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%7D%20==%20%7Ba,%20b,%20c,%20d%7D,%20%7Bx,%20y,%20z%7D%5D), and the result is scary.

Comment: Thank you @B.S. that is exactly where I found various of representation in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: the scheme you are using for injectivity does not applied 'cuz $f$ is not linear

Comment: Cross-Cap is not an embedding or injective. It is actually a representation(not embedding or injective) of $RP^2$ in $R^3$.